# Two row responsive navigation script/framework

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I wanted to make a navigation bar which uses two main rows, but the catch is the second row options can, themselves, have more options (which would be accessed by a hover/dropdown).

I've attached a picture of what I was hoping to achieve (although the image doesn't include the sub-sub navigation).

Has anyone seen a framework/script (commercial or free) that does something like this that I could work off of?

Thanks so much[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D  Sorry about that, which of the sites would this fall into?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Foundation framework for frontend stuff, or Bootstrap. In foundation, you would use a grid system, and with it, you are just a control away of showing/hiding elements depending on the screen size. I hope this short answer helps.